# Is population of field with a type of array of ObjId even possiple?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I've came across this wired behavior when trying to populate tags and categories fields.

here are portion of the article model

```
tags: {
    type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
    index: true,
    ref: 'tag'
},

categories: {
        type: [mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId],
        index: true,
        ref: 'category'
    }
```

by trying to populate theses three fields only author works since it is not arrray of objects

```
    .populate('author')
    .populate('tags')
    .populate('categgories')
```

look at the mongoose debug result and note that mongoose is calling article model not tag to populate tags and so categories, therefor population is not working .

```
Mongoose: users.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5b83eacb51e2d33dd5c057ad") ] } }, { fields: { name: 1 } })
Mongoose: articles.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5b83eac851e2d33dd5c057ab") ] } }, { fields: { _id: 1 } })
Mongoose: articles.find({ _id: { '$in': [ ObjectId("5b83eac951e2d33dd5c057ac") ] } }, { fields: {} })
```

Comment: why mongoose called articles.find instead of tags.find?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.

But you need to tell mongoose which model to search in by

```
populate({path:"path",model:"model"})
```

otherwise mongoose will hit find query on the parent model instead of the child noting that this approach is required in array case only